# How do I redirect System.out, System.err to the log file

Tags: java, logging, log4j, stdout, jnlp

I want to see my jnlp stdout in a log file.
Please suggest.
P.S.
I jnlp is run under windows and log4j logger is used

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200175/log4j-redirect-stdout-to-dailyrollingfileappender

Comment: Possible Duplicate: **[Redirect System.out and System.err](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715748/redirect-system-out-and-system-err)** and **[Redirect System.out and System.err to slf4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187461/redirect-system-out-and-system-err-to-slf4j)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The System class has a setOut() and setErr() methods that can be used to change the output stream.

Comment: is it possible to configure this via xml?