# getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD exception

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm working on Apache POI ppt project and getting this exception but not able to figure out what's wrong here?

```
10:46:45.903 [main] DEBUG org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage - Save content types part
10:46:45.927 [main] WARN org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper - SAX Feature unsupported [log suppressed for 5 minutes]http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD
    at org.docx4j.org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.setAttribute(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:571)
    at org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper.trySet(XMLHelper.java:284)
    at org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper.getTransformerFactory(XMLHelper.java:224)
    at org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper.newTransformer(XMLHelper.java:231)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.StreamHelper.saveXmlInStream(StreamHelper.java:56)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipContentTypeManager.saveImpl(ZipContentTypeManager.java:68)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ContentTypeManager.save(ContentTypeManager.java:450)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:554)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1487)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:227)
    at com.iep.generator.PptCreater.createPpt(PptCreater.java:526)
    at com.iep.generator.PptCreater.main(PptCreater.java:94)
10:46:45.970 [main] DEBUG org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage - Save package relationships
```

Note : My code is working fine, even with this exception.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable accessExternalDTD and entityExpansionLimit warnings with logback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25453042/how-to-disable-accessexternaldtd-and-entityexpansionlimit-warnings-with-logback)

Comment: Install a non-broken XML parser, or otherwise live with the warnings about the security hardening that won't work?

Comment: using Jsoup. @Gagravarr

Comment: Not using  xerces jar anywhere in my project @cyberbrain

Comment: Did you check your transitive dependencies as well?

Comment: This is just a warning log message - it shouldn't stop POI working - that docx4j jar embeds a shaded xalan instance that is causing the issues - docx4j should stop doing that or embed a newer version of xalan

Comment: Yes, You are correct my code is working fine but can you suggest any way to get rid of it? @PJFanning

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue. I was able to solve this by using extension as .xls instead of .xlsx