# Correct way to System.setErr() for multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, io, outputstream

So I've got a Java application using a fixed thread pool to execute some code. This code includes use of a third-party library that outputs to System.err. When I had this chunk of code executing single-threaded, I "redirected" System.err to a PrintStream that ultimately ended up printing out to log4j logs. Basically it looked like this:

```
 PrintStream oldErr = System.err;
 System.setErr(new PrintStream(/* custom logging stream here */));

 try
 {
     // do computationally expensive task here
 }
 finally
 {
     System.setErr(oldErr);
 }
```

That worked as expected. The output printed to the logfiles instead of the console, and I could remove the output entirely by changing my log4j configuration. Perfect.

When I started to add multithreading I did a little research and came across this SO question: [In a multithreaded Java program, does each thread have its own copy of System.out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015182/in-a-multithreaded-java-program-does-each-thread-have-its-own-copy-of-system-ou), which implied that I should do System.setErr() once before firing up my thread pool and I'd be all set. Only that doesn't appear to be the case. My code looks like this now:

```
 PrintStream oldErr = System.err;
 System.setErr(new PrintStream(/* custom logging stream here */));

 ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxThreadCount);

 try
 {
     // shove computationally expensive task off to a thread
     //   using threadPool.execute()
 }
 finally
 {
     System.setErr(oldErr);
 }
```

However, calling System.setErr() before firing up the thread pool has zero effect. The threads all print their output to System.err as if I had not made the call at all. Drat!

I also tried having the threads call System.setErr() while executing their tasks, but there were some clear race condition issues with that--intermittent output to the console, and a general feeling of dirtiness. In one test run it even looked like they deadlocked.

Am I missing something simple? FWIW, here are my JVM details:

```
java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b17, mixed mode)
```

Thanks.

EDIT: My issue was basically solved by the accepted answer, but for sake of completeness I wanted to add that I could not solve my particular case using Futures and `get()`. My individual tasks consume a lot of RAM but vary in duration, so I had to go with a small blocking queue as outlined in the answer to [Java: ExecutorService that blocks on submission after a certain queue size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521983/java-executorservice-that-blocks-on-submission-after-a-certain-queue-size). I basically fell into the trap of thinking that the defaults in `newFixedThreadPool()` would work for my situation when in reality they did not, and Brian's answer helped expose those faulty assumptions. Thanks Brian!

Comment: I suspect the problem is the fact that the `final` keyword on the `System` streams means something different than it does in the entire rest of Java, and it has its own "write-protected" semantics. You may be getting instruction reordering regarding the launching of the thread pool. Try putting in a useless `volatile Object` class variable and calling its `hashCode()` method in between calling `setErr` and initializing your thread pool.

Comment: @chrylis Actually, `final` in `System` has the same semantics as in the rest of java: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3301720/2299084.

Comment: It sounds like you need to redirect `System.err` in each thread and make `/* custom logging stream here */` thread safe.

Comment: @chrylis thanks, I'm trying that "trick" but for some reason my program immediately exits when I try to use it. No messages, exit code 1, perhaps the messages are swallowed because I redirected System.err :). Unfortunately I have to go, so I'll try some more tomorrow.

Comment: Can you post some actual code? As it is in your snippit if you're not blocking and waiting for those tasks to finish in the `try` block, `System.err` is going to instantly get reset in the `finally` block.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Perhaps but I have my doubts about that. When I mentioned "intermittent output" above I meant that I would see fragments of output printed to System.err and fragments printed to my logfile. In both cases the output was coherent. If the instruction reordering fix doesn't work then I will explore this possibility more thoroughly.

Comment: @user60561 [No, it doesn't.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following SSCCE does exactly what you want and are expecting:

```
public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException 
    {
        PrintStream oldErr = System.err;
        System.setErr(new PrintStream(new File("test")));

        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        List<Future<?>> fList = new LinkedList<Future<?>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            fList.add(threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    System.err.println("This is to the err stream");
                }

            }));
        }

        for (Future<?> f : fList)
        {
            f.get();
        }

        threadPool.shutdown();

        System.setErr(oldErr);
        System.err.println("This is to the err stream");
    }
}
```

After running this example, the file "test" contains 5 lines, each saying "This is to the err stream" and at the end one additional line is printed to the console.

The code snippet you show is calling `System.setErr(oldErr);` in the `finally` block ... have you waited for all your tasks to complete in that `try` block?

If not it would explain the statement you make in the comments that *"I would see fragments of output printed to System.err and fragments printed to my logfile"* ... that's pretty much what you'd expect to happen. `.submit()` is a non-blocking call that returns a `Future`; you're resetting the stream while your tasks are running.

Comment: What my snippet didn't show was a call to `threadPool.shutdown()`. I thought that call made the main thread block until tasks were done but I now realize it does not. I've modified my code to call both `threadPool.shutdown()` and `threadPool.awaitTermination()` before resetting `System.err` in order to avoid the problem. Your answer did point me in the right direction, thanks!