# Java separate System.out for separate Classpath

Tags: java, jenkins, classloader, system.out

I am developing an application which needs to call some Jenkins instances, to do this I am using the jenkins-cli .jar
I could be calling the jar using the commandline to easily extract its output. Then however I need to parse exceptions myself.
To properly handle exceptions I am now invoking the main method of the jar via reflection:

```
URLClassLoader jenkinsClassloader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{"UrlToJenkins-Cli.jar"}, getClass().getClassLoader());
Class<?> jenkinsCli = Class.forName ("hudson.cli.CLI", false, jenkinsClassloader);
Method mainMethod = jenkinsCli.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);
mainMethod.invoke (null, (Object) commandArray);
```

But now I need to somehow get the output the jar prints to System.out
I know I can use `System.setOut()`. The problem there is that I have other threads logging simultaniously.
I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015182/in-a-multithreaded-java-program-does-each-thread-have-its-own-copy-of-system-ou) that System.out is classloader specific, but I couldn't find any additional information about this.
Does someone know a way to get the stdout of the jar without it being interfered with from other threads?

Comment: That other answer is wrong: `System.out` is definitely not class loader specific.  Perhaps you could use `System.setOut` so that the `PrintStream` was caller-sensitive, but it doesn't do that by default either.

Comment: Ah I see, I hoped for there to be an easy solution. Thanks for clearing things up

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to create a custom class extending [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html), that would simply pass whatever is passed to it to another `PrintStream`, then wrap that around `System.out`, via `System.setOut()`; the custom class could have a [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) private attribute that could be used to tell it if, for the current thread, the text should be intercepted.

Not the most elegant of solutions, but could be a good fallback if no alternative is found.